# How to get the bounds of an svg path precisely in HTML?

Tags: html, svg, colors, path, clip

I need to get the outside of an svg path to be colored differently from the inside of the path area. 
The best solution I found is to add a rectangle before the path inside the svg tag, then to color this rectangle with the specific color I want.
The problem is that I'm not getting the precise dimensions (x,y, width,height) to draw such rectangle. However when I hover an the path element in the html code showed the browser (inspect) the path element is highlighted with a precise rectangle, how can I get the dimensions of such rectangle ?

Here is a code sample:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%" id="id49">
    <rect x="16.0" y="4.0" width="282.0" height="117.0" style="fill:rgba(255, 102, 0, 255);stroke-width:0; "></rect>
    <path fill="rgba(51, 51, 0, 255)" id="id49_path" d="M 216.0 4.0 L 282.0 22.0 L 183.0 35.0 L 215.0 103.0 C 110.0 -43.0 95.0 112.0 35.0 117.0 C 29.0 95.0 -14.0 91.0 16.0 50.0 C 58.0 -56.0 44.0 43.0 58.0 40.0 L 86.0 17.0 C 101.0 45.0 98.0 77.0 130.0 100.0 C 139.0 -4.0 147.0 93.0 155.0 90.0 C 175.0 61.0 293.0 55.0 216.0 4.0" style="pointer-events: visiblePainted; transform: rotate(0deg);"></path>
</svg>
```

FYI: the shape is designed in java and I need to write its code in html.

Comment: call path.getBBox() where path is your path element.

Comment: You have to remove last sentence in your post because your shape is in XML.

Comment: Seems Batik [does not support](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/dom-api.html#buildsvgdoc) the .getBBox() method.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  @Bharata, My last sentence is important, because I'm more interested in getting such information from the java code if it possible, the path is generated from a Path2D in java but the getBounds2D() method is not giving the precise dimensions. Otherwise I will use JS to get them. Actually It is a generated html code.